# List won't update after inserting related list

Tags: apex, controller, list-view

I have a list view button that creates related sales order records based on the selected service contracts and their values. The creation of the sales orders works, but when I try to update those same service contracts with the newly created sales orders in a lookup field, it won't update that service contracts list. I assume it is because the sales order ID hasn't been created yet when I assign it to the lookup field, but I don't know how to do it right. Any help is appreciated.

```
public class bulkServiceContractConversion_Controller {
    //Create variables
    private ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController;
    List <gii__SalesOrder__c> salesOrderList = new List<gii__SalesOrder__c>();
    List<ServiceContract> contractList = new List<ServiceContract>();
    
    //Constructor
    public bulkServiceContractConversion_Controller(ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController)
    {
        this.standardController = standardController;
        if (!Test.isRunningTest()) standardController.addFields(new String[]{'AccountId', 'Payment_Schedule__c'});
    }
    
    //Method to generate Sales Orders from Service Contracts
    public PageReference convert() {
        
        //Get record type for "Contract Order"
        Id soRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.gii__SalesOrder__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Contract Order').getRecordTypeId();
        
        //Get the selected records
        List<ServiceContract> selectedContracts = (List<ServiceContract>) standardController.getSelected();
        
        for (ServiceContract selectedContract : selectedContracts)
        {
            //Create Sales Orders
            gii__SalesOrder__c salesOrder = new gii__SalesOrder__c();
            salesOrder.RecordTypeId = soRecordTypeId;
            salesOrder.gii__OrderType__c = 'Standard';
            salesOrder.Service_Contract__c = selectedContract.Id;
            salesOrder.gii__Account__c = selectedContract.AccountId;
            salesOrder.Payment_Schedule__c = selectedContract.Payment_Schedule__c;
            
            
            //Update Service Contract
            selectedContract.Sales_Order__c = salesOrder.Id;
            
            //Add to lists
            salesOrderList.add(salesOrder);
            contractList.add(selectedContract);
        }
        
        //Insert sales orders
        insert salesOrderList;
        
        //Update service contracts
        update contractList;
        
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: your assumption is correct - this is where the [UnitOfWork pattern](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_patterns_sl/apex_patterns_sl_learn_uow_principles) comes in handy

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing in case anyone else runs into this, or for feedback on how to make my code better. I'm still new to the development side of Salesforce.

```
public class bulkServiceContractConversion_Controller {
    //Create variables
    private ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController;
    Map<Integer, gii__SalesOrder__c> salesOrderMap = new Map<Integer, gii__SalesOrder__c>();
    Integer index = 0;
    Integer counter = 0;
    
    //Constructor
    public bulkServiceContractConversion_Controller(ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController)
    {
        this.standardController = standardController;
        if (!Test.isRunningTest()) standardController.addFields(new String[]{'AccountId', 'Payment_Schedule__c'});
    }
    
    //Method to generate Sales Orders from Service Contracts
    public PageReference convert() {
        
        //Get record type for "Contract Order"
        Id soRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.gii__SalesOrder__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Contract Order').getRecordTypeId();
        
        //Get the selected records
        List<ServiceContract> selectedContracts = (List<ServiceContract>) standardController.getSelected();
        
        for (ServiceContract selectedContract : selectedContracts)
        {
            //Create Sales Orders
            gii__SalesOrder__c salesOrder = new gii__SalesOrder__c();
            salesOrder.RecordTypeId = soRecordTypeId;
            salesOrder.gii__OrderType__c = 'Standard';
            salesOrder.Service_Contract__c = selectedContract.Id;
            salesOrder.gii__Account__c = selectedContract.AccountId;
            salesOrder.Payment_Schedule__c = selectedContract.Payment_Schedule__c;
            
            //Add Sales Order to map to insert
            salesOrderMap.put(index++, salesOrder);
        }
        
        //Insert sales orders
        insert salesOrderMap.values();
        
        for (ServiceContract selectedContract : selectedContracts) {
            gii__SalesOrder__c salesOrder = salesOrderMap.get(counter++);
            selectedContract.Sales_Order__c = salesOrder.id;
        }
        
        //Update service contracts
        update selectedContracts;

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad you figured this out; the above works as you have a 1:1 association based on position 0..n  of the related recs. If you study the UnitOfWork pattern, you can see a more general solution that allows for any arbitrary association between the parent and child (e.g. parent 1 has children a,b,c; parent 2 has no children; parent 3 has children d,e; etc)